# Access violation initializing a structure

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, stack, rpn

I've done a code for an RPN calculator, it works fine for basic operators (+, *, /, ^) as well for floating point and negative numbers. It also evaluates expressions like
 (x^2 + x*4/-2) : 1 -> 5 :0.5 (x evaluated from 1 to 5, steps of 0.5)

I used a **char stack.**

Now, I want to add support for functions such as cos(x), tan(x). In order to reach that purpose, I need to build a **char* stack**, storing the words like sin, cos, sqrt, etc after parsing.

The problem is that, when initializing the stack, i get a "**access violation: write of address 0x01**" error.

I don't know exactly why. Could it be the use of malloc()?

These are the functions for the use of the stack.

```
typedef struct nodo{
    char *operador;
    struct nodo *next;
}tipo;

typedef tipo *elemento;
typedef tipo *top;

int push(top*,char*) ;
void init(top *);
void libera(top*);
char* pop(top*);


int main(){
    (...)
    top op;
    init(&op);
    (...)
}


void init(top *pila) {
    *pila = malloc(sizeof(**pila));
    (*pila)->operador = NULL;
    (*pila)->next = NULL;
}

void libera(top *pila) {
    free(*pila);
    *pila = NULL;
}


int push (top *last,char *dato){
    elemento new1;
    int j=strlen(dato);
    new1 = (elemento)malloc(sizeof(tipo));
    strncpy(new1->operador, dato,j);
    new1->next=*last;
    *last=new1;
;}


char* pop(top *last){
    elemento aux;
    char* caract;
    aux = (elemento)malloc(sizeof(tipo));
    aux=*last;
    if (!aux)
        return 0;
    *last=aux->next;
    strcpy(caract,aux->operador);
    free(aux);
    return caract;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change...

```
*pila = malloc(sizeof(**pila));
```

to...

```
*pila = malloc(sizeof(tipo));
```

Comment: It didn't work, as well, i get the same "access violation" error.
Thanks !

Comment: What are you passing to init? Please show the declaration.

Comment: int main ()
    {
    (...)
    top op;
    init(&op);
    (...)
    }

Comment: @n3rd4n1 the original code is better than your suggestion

Comment: @MattMcNabb how could a code that twists your brain better than a straightforward one?

Comment: @n3rd4n1 my thoughts precisely. The first one is obviously correct; the second one, we can't tell without investigating what the type of `pila` is (which is extra twisty due to all the pointer typedefs).

Comment: @MattMcNabb I presented the second code after analyzing what the malloc is trying to achieve. It assigns the pointer to `top` which is a `pointer to tipo`, which means storage size should be `sizeof(tipo)`. And I agree, the code above is not the most beatiful code, no offense @Audo.

Comment: @n3rd4n1 the point is that you do not need to do any analysis for the first version. It is obviously correct.   However your suggestion requires analysis to determine whether it is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug (in two different ways):

```
new1 = (elemento)malloc(sizeof(tipo));
strncpy(new1->operador, dato,j);
```

The `strncpy` does not generate a string (i.e. it does not place a null terminator) because you specified a buffer size which is not big enough. The third argument is the *output buffer size*, not the input length.

Further, `new1->operador` is an uninitialized pointer. You didn't malloc any space for it.

To fix this, perhaps do:

```
init(&new1);
new1->operador = malloc( strlen(dato) + 1 );
strcpy(new1->operador, dato);
```

---

Here is another bug:

```
aux = (elemento)malloc(sizeof(tipo));
aux=*last;
```

`aux` is a pointer here (in disguise since you used pointer typedefs). The second line makes it point to where `*last` is pointing to, leaking the memory. You probably wanted to copy the data pointed to by `*last`, into the space pointed to by `aux`:

```
*aux = **last;
```

But then you have another bug:

```
strcpy(caract,aux->operador);
```

You didn't make `caract` point anywhere yet.

---

There might be bugs elsewhere in your code; I just noticed these ones so far. Your code is very difficult to read because of all the pointer typedefs.  It would help if you got rid of the pointer typedefs.

I suggest you don't write so much code at once; write one function, and then test it thoroughly, once you are sure it is working then move onto the next function.

Comment: There are more bugs. Just noticed this one: `aux = malloc(...); aux=*last;` in the pop function. Allocates memory and immediately loses a reference to it.

Comment: Thanks to both ! I've already done the changes you indicate, and is still the same error at init(), in the line

    `*pila = malloc(sizeof(**pila)); //`

Comment: That means you are calling `init` somewhere with a wild pointer (or perhaps you invoked undefined behaviour elsewhere ).  To get better help, post a real program that gives the problem.